# Is killing an enemy scout considered a battle?

Tags: civilization-board-game

The game manual says that if you conquer an enemy scout that is alone, you can take a loot **as if you had won a battle**. It doesn't specify that it *is a battle*.

The reason we need to know is for **Code of Laws**. Upon winning a battle, you can get a coin token to place on that research for future investing. So is conquering a scout that is alone considered a battle?

Comment: In the PC edition, killing a Scout does not net a benefit *a la* looting or similar.

Comment: The manual does say that loot is gained, and it has already been made known that a battle does not take place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No. If you aren't drawing square unit cards, a battle isn't taking place**

From the [FFG rule book (page 23)](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/civilization/support/civilization-rules.pdf)

> Battle is the struggle of one civilization against another for dominance. When an army figure moves into a square containing a village marker, an enemy army figure, or an enemy city, a battle takes place.

If you had continued reading the section ENEMY FIGURES, you should have realized that.

> Scouts cannot enter a square containing enemy figures. If an army enters a square containing any enemy figures, its movement immediately ends. If the square contains only enemy scouts, the scouts are immediately killed and the attacking player collects loot as though they had won a battle (see page 25). **If the square contains at least one enemy army, a battle occurs (see page 23).** If the square contains a mix of both enemy armies and scouts, a battle occurs, but if the losing side in the battle has any scouts in the square, they are killed along with the armies; loot is then collected as normal.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did read that, but it doesn't say "only if" which is why I wanted to ask.

Comment: Huh? What says, "only if"? IF [...] only enemy scouts THEN [...] kill scouts collect loot. IF at least one enemy army THEN battle. If a mix of scouts/armies THEN battle AND IF loser has scouts kill them too.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, trust me. I'm saying that it just says, "If the square contains at least one enemy army, a battle occurs". It does not say that if the square contains only an enemy scout that a battle occurs. The second block doesn't help verify the answer, but the first part definitely did. So you did answer it, and I marked it as correct. No worries, sir.